# trying to vectorize this operation in R and I don't see why this is wrong

Tags: r, vectorization, apply

I want to loop through a data frame and create a new column that says 'YES' if the 2nd to 4th elements in the row are 'ANOMALY' and 'NO' otherwise.

```
for (j in 1:nrow(residual_anomalies)){
  if (all(residual_anomalies[j,2:4]=='ANOMALY')) {residual_anomalies$Prediction_Anomaly[j] <- 'YES'} else
    residual_anomalies$Prediction_Anomaly[j] <- 'NO'
}
```

So the above is currently what I'm using. It works but it's taking a big computational performance hit so I'm trying to vectorize it. What I had done so far was create a function that returns 'YES' or 'NO' based on if the elements of the row were all 'ANOMALY'.

```
vote_for_anomaly <- function(x){
  if (all(x)=='ANOMALY') return('YES') else
    return('NO')}
```

And then I try to use the apply function in R

```
 aggregates <- apply(residual_anomalies[,2:4],1,vote_for_anomaly)
```

but then I'm getting the following errors/warnings

```
Error in if (all(x) == "ANOMALY") return("ANOMALY") else return("NO SIGNAL") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In all(x) : coercing argument of type 'character' to logical
```

Can someone tell me why this isn't working and how I should change this?

You can use this data for testing and call it `residual_anomalies`

```
1     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY
2     ANOMALY     NO SIGNAL     ANOMALY     ANOMALY
3     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY
4     NO SIGNAL     ANOMALY     NO SIGNAL     ANOMALY
5     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY     ANOMALY
6     NO SIGNAL     NO SIGNAL     ANOMALY     ANOMALY
```

Comment: Maybe `if (all(x =='ANOMALY')) ...`?

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it was something that minor...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be quicker to do this using indexing, rather than `ifelse()`. First set up a vector of `No` of required length:

```
aggregates <- rep("No", NROW(residual_anomalies))
```

Then just index this vector where all `residual_anomalies[, 2:4] == "ANOMALY"`

```
aggregates[rowSums(residual_anomalies[, 2:4] == "ANOMALY") == 3L] <- "Yes"
```

This gives:

```
> aggregates
[1] "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "No"
```

This part `residual_anomalies[, 2:4] == "ANOMALY"` creates a logical matrix:

```
> residual_anomalies[, 2:4] == "ANOMALY"
        V2    V3   V4
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

When we take the `rowsums()`, `TRUE` is converted to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. Hence only those rows where all elements are `TRUE` will get selected and assigned `"Yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

Per @lukeA, there's a typo in your code. It should be

```
all(x == "ANOMALY")
```

but it would be faster to do:

```
residual_anomalies$Prediction_Anomaly <-
  ifelse(rowSums(residual_anomalies[, 2:4] == "ANOMALY") == 3, "YES", "NO")
```

rowSums is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

As @lukeA said you have mixed up your parentheses, but here is a simpler over all solution as well:

```
aggregates <- ifelse(apply(residual_anomalies, 1, 
     function(x) all(x[2:4] == "ANOMALY")), "YES", "NO")
```